# A função faz escrita no arquivo no txt. Preciso fazer a soma mas o vetor está como char

Tags: c

Meu professor passou esse código que faz escriva no arquivo txt. Insere número aleatórios. Depois de executar esse código ele quer que eu faça a soma dos valores escritos no txt, mas eles foram escritos em um vetor de char e para eu fazer a soma eu preciso converte-los. E mostrar essa soma na tela. Entende?

Texto escrito no txt:

```
333;60;565;212;657;95;364;486;860;
68;859;649;573;475;631;389;698;467;
952;14;834;912;163;678;929;518;85;
151;123;413;76;435;948;405;576;312;
608;708;339;814;582;278;36;498;218;
788;234;728;300;368;151;444;339;767;
75;42;141;368;163;912;971;469;1;
760;665;136;614;938;460;320;118;473;
599;795;411;876;79;590;644;64;910;
```

Segue código:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<time.h>

void main(){
int i, j , x;
char vetor[50];
FILE *arq;

arq = fopen("dados.txt", "w");
srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            x = rand() % 1000 +1;
            fprintf(arq, "%d;", x);
        }
    fprintf(arq, "\n");
    }
fclose(arq);

//Faz a leitura:

arq = fopen("dados.txt", "r");

while(!feof(arq)){
    fscanf(arq, "%d;%d;d%;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;",&vetor[0], &vetor[1], &vetor[2], &vetor[3], &vetor[4], &vetor[5], &vetor[6], &vetor[7], &vetor[8] );

    for(i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("[%d]=%d\t", i, vetor[i]);           
    }
    printf("\n");
}
fclose(arq);
```

}

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem o que vc quer fazer? Poderia ser mais especifico e acrescentar mais detalhes a pergunta?

Comment: Específica*. Certo vou tentar.

Comment: Me desculpe, não sabia que se tratava de uma garota. Como esta o arquivo de texto e como vc gostaria que ficasse a saída?

Comment: :) Tudo bem. Editei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você tem valores maiores que **255** então não pode usar um vetor `char` seu vetor deve ser um `int`.

```
int vetor[50];
```

Para fazer a soma, use um `for` dentro do `while`.

```
int line;
while(!feof(arq)){
    //...
    line = 0;
    for(i=0;x<8;i++){
        line += vetor[i]
    }
    printf("Soma da linha: %d\n", line)
}
```

Comment: Maior que 255, onde? Não entendi.

Comment: @gonz Logo na primeira linha vc tem `333;60;565;...` e a variável do tipo char só suporta valores até 255, por isso que  seu vetor deve ser inteiro

Comment: Não sei disso não.

Comment: @gonz: POr que você marocua resposta como correta se não entendeu e ela nao resolveu seu porblema? Isso faz com que uoturas pessoa que possam ter entendido melhor seu problema, e talvez pudessem te explicar a relação de "char" com 255 respondam, já que você já tem uma resposta aceita. 
Esclareça suas duvidas, faça o que voce tem funcionar, e ai sim aceite a resposta.

Comment: Não é isso. Ela resolveu o meu problema, eu só não fiquei confiante com o 255. Eu tenho que estudar sobre isso.

Comment: Tipos `char` são bytes, na maioria das implementações de linguagem C. E bytes têm 8 bits. E cada bit pode assumir dois valores. Dois elevado a oito é 256. Os bytes permitem representar até 256 estados. Se o primeiro estado for 0, o seguinte será 1, e depois 2, até 255.